# Internal memory in iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I just finished the second tutorial for iOS development. When I add a new sighting, it works fine and turns up in the list of sightings. However, when I close the iOS simulator and reopen it, only the first entry is there (it is added manually). Should there be internal memory in the iOS simulator even after it is closed and reopened? 
There seems to be some memory as if I add my contact info to the contacts, it is still there when I reopen it.
If so, how do I make sure that my array in the DataController file is similarly stored on the simulator/phone so it doesn't clear itself every time I reopen the simulator?

Thanks

Comment: There's no "internal memory" unless you define it somehow.  You need to write to Core Data or to your own database.

Comment: (Or, if I read that a different way, if you're referencing a database you've installed, it needs to be copied to writable storage during initialization, or it's effectively read-only.)

Comment: Simulator simulate your iPhone functionality. The apps that you run are in the background even if you reopen the simulator they will be there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use persistent storage if you want to save data between sessions. Options include:

1. You can use plist files. For example if you have `NSArray *array`, you can save that to a plist using [`writeToFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCGEFF):

   ```
   [array writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
   ```

   You can then read this array with:

   ```
   NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filename];
   ```

   This technique only works with standard `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc., objects, not custom objects like `BirdSighting`, though.
2. For custom objects like `BirdSighting`, you could use [`NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i). By the way, these are not only generally useful classes for saving data for small data sets like this, but given that it features prominently in the new iOS 6 state preservation features, it's worth familiarizing yourself with this pattern.
3. You can use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i). This is really better suited for app settings and defaults, but theoretically could be used for saving data, too.
4. You can use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). This is the preferred iOS technology for object persistence. It's a powerful and well engineered framework (though a tad complicated) and well suited if you're dealing with more significant amounts of data.
5. You can use [SQLite](http://sqlite.org), too. See this [Ray Wenderlich article on using SQLite](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app). And once you start using SQLite, you can consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to simplify your coding effort.

---

If you wanted, for example, to use the second approach, `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, the first thing is that you might want to do is make `BirdSighting` conform to `NSCoding`, by altering the `@interface` declaration in `BirdSighting.h` to say:

```
@interface BirdSighting : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

Second, you have to write the two `NSCoding` methods, `initWithCoder` and `encodeWithCoder`, in `BirdSighting.m` that define what properties can to be loaded/saved for this object:

```
- (NSArray *)keysForEncoding;
{
    return @[@"name", @"location", @"date"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        for (NSString *key in [self keysForEncoding])
        {
            [self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    for (NSString *key in self.keysForEncoding)
    {
        [aCoder encodeObject:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Your `BirdSighting` can now be loaded and saved with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and `NSKeyedArchiver`, respectively.

So, focusing on the loading of the sightings, you have to (a) tell `BirdSightingDataController.m` what file to look for; and (b) instruct it to read that file during initialization:

```
- (NSString *)filename
{
    NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    return [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BirdSightings"];
}

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList
{
    NSString *filename = [self filename];

    self.masterBirdSightingList = nil;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filename])
    {
        self.masterBirdSightingList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filename];
    }

    if (!self.masterBirdSightingList)
    {
        NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;
        BirdSighting *sighting;
        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:@"Pigeon" location:@"Everywhere" date:today];
        [self addBirdSightingWithSighting:sighting];
    }
}
```

The `BirdSightingDataController.m` can also define a method to save the data:

```
- (BOOL)save
{
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.masterBirdSightingList toFile:[self filename]];
}
```

You can now, for example, call this `save` method whenever you add a sighting, e.g.:

```
- (void)addBirdSightingWithSighting:(BirdSighting *)sighting
{
    [self.masterBirdSightingList addObject:sighting];

    [self save];
}
```

Personally, rather than saving it every time a user does any change in the app, I might rather just have my app delegate save it when the app goes into background or terminates (but that requires further changes, so I won't go into that now).

But hopefully this code illustrates how you can use `NSKeyArchiver` and `NSKeyUnarchiver` to save and load data. And clearly, for more complicated scenarios, I would generally encourage you to consider Core Data. But for small data sets, like this, this archiver pattern can be useful (and as I said, is worth being familiar with because the basic technology is also used in iOS 6 app state restoration).